Should "the park" be capitalized when referring to Central Park?
I am writing a piece about Central Park in New York City. "Central Park" is a proper noun and should be capitalized. Here's my question: when I use "the park" (or "the Park") to refer to Central Park should that word be capitalized?

It is considered reasonable by some to abbreviate a multi-part proper noun such as Central Park to the Park, retaining proper-noun specification (the capital).
Thus the House of Representatives, the larger part of the U.S. Congress or of the Parliament of Australia (and†, pre-'unicameralisation', New Zealand), is referred to in short as the House.  [Merriam-Webster]
Another example:


Heartbreaking reason Kensington Palace announced in ...

The news comes after the Palace released a devastating message from The Princess of Wales this evening ...

[The Mirror, 22 Mar 2024]
But the usual practice is to revert to the common noun (lower-cased) on subsequent mentions where the complete title is considered too lengthy to keep repeating. This wouldn't happen with the House, but does with say the Palace:


In late February, the palace released photographs of Charles reading
some of the cards and letters from well-wishe[r]s ....


[ABC News; 22 Mar 2024]
It's probably influenced by how comfortable it feels to use the common noun variant in what is arguably still a 'proper role'. 'The house' looks perhaps too ordinary, while 'the palace' still has a cachet. Thus one can find the occasional (ie smallish minority usage)  lower-casing of 'parliament' when it is obviously being used as a title, as in


Av Dicey said that parliament can make or unmake any law on any subject whatever, without legal restriction. This principle stems from
the election of MPs ....


[Marked By Teachers]
With Central Park, there is divided usage, some preferring always to convey esteem:


Central Park Conservancy: Your Official Guide to Central Park ...

Help the Central Park Conservancy keep the Park beautiful and vibrant by making a gift today.

[Central Park Conservancy]
while some think a park is a park:


How to visit Central Park for the first time

There is no fee to enter the park[;] however certain attractions such as the Central Park Zoo, Wollman Rink, and boating rentals, require
....

[The Empty Nest Explorers; 14 Aug 2024]
(This divided usage seems to occur with various different Central Parks.)
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[† thanks to jsw29 for their advice on political correctness]

I guess there's a difference between Central Park which is a park and the House of Representatives which isn't a house in the common meaning of the word. So capitalising House is more natural.

Also with the Oxford namesake; 'the House' is the usual nickname for Christ Church [college]. Sometimes the 'the' is also capitalised.
